# Why we need training and test datasets in research?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I'm newbie in research area of data mining (text clustering) and i have couple question regarding to training and test datasets.

1. Is that clustering need training and testing datasets?
2. why we need to separate into training and test datasets?

Sorry for the rookie question hope expert in this group can help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your question is on clustering:

**In cluster analysis, there usually is no training or test data split**.

Because you do cluster analysis when you **do not have labels**, so you cannot "train".

Training is a concept from machine learning, and train-test splitting is used to *avoid overfitting*.

But **if you are not learning labels, you cannot overfit**.

Properly used cluster analysis is a *knowledge discovery* method. You want to discover some new structure in your data, not rediscover something that is already labeled.

Comment: What about during evaluation and measurement we need a class/label is that rite?

Comment: There are three approaches for validation: 1. class labels (however, then you are actually doing unsupervised classification) 2. internal measures (however this is heavily biased towards methods that optimize this particular measure) 3. **manual evaluation** this is boring, but most sound. If an expert finds the result useful, then you truly achieved the objective.

Answer (score 0):

1. To train your data you need a sets of relevant data similar but not identical to your testing data. For example, you could split up your data where 0.7 of your data is training and the rest testing. This will allow your algorithm to get a feel for what it should be looking for. The rest of the data 0.3 can be used for testing as it is a distinct set of information (hopefully) which should allow the algorithm to test itself.
2. Why split it up?
   Well if you train your data on data A and then test your algorithm on data A your algorithm will be able to identify all the information correctly because that is what it was trained on.

For example, if when learning addition you were given the sums 3+4, 4+5, 6+9, which you correctly solved it would be redundant to test your knowledge of addition using the same sums.

further information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

http://www.nltk.org/book

Hope this helps.